# Is it safe to delete the innodb schema on a new Amazon RDS instance?

Tags: mysql, innodb, amazon-rds

As per the title, I'm struggling to find out if it's safe to delete the `innodb` schema that's created on a fresh Amazon RDS instance.

```
mysql> SHOW DATABASES;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| innodb             | -- This was automatically created when the instance was created
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
+--------------------+
```

I know it's not doing any harm being sat there - there's no tables/content or anything, I'm just curious as to why it's there and I've not been able to find out why from any other sources.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a reason you cannot touch the innodb database.

This is where Amazon stores the system tablespace file `ibdata1`

If you run

```
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_data_home_dir';
```

you might see something like this

```
/rdsdbdata/db/innodb
```

It will point to this folder as the base of InnoDB.

If you run

```
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_log_group_home_dir';
```

you might see something like this

```
/rdsdbdata/log/innodb
```

This is where `ib_logfile0` and `ib_logfile1` live.

If you run

```
use innodb
show tables;
```

you will see nothing because there are no `.frm` files in it.

Even though the innodb database contains no storage engine data files (`.frm` or `.ibd`), you cannot drop the `innodb` database because the folder `/rdsdbdata/db/innodb` is not empty.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, regardless of whether it's safe to delete the `innodb` schema or not, RDS won't let you do it anyway (tested on a temporary test instance):

```
DROP DATABASE `innodb`;

Error dropping database (can't rmdir './innodb/', errno: 17)
```

Comment: There's a mention of the same error here, so I guess it's there by design: http://ronaldbradford.com/blog/when-is-a-database-schema-not-a-database-schema-2012-04-18/